# Unable to connect to mongod using hostname from pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo to connect to mongod. 
The following code works

```
def init_db():
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test_db
return db
```

However, when I change 'localhost' above to my machine's hostname, like so

```
def init_db():
client = MongoClient('p-linux', 27017)
db = client.test_db
return db
```

it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I resolved my problem by starting mongod with the --bind_ip_all option (of course, after turning on authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing following in **/etc/mongod.conf** file.

```
# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces. 
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

And restart the service by

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Commenting out #bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 will open it to anyone/anywhere. Make sure you either has your firewall/iptables filtering unsolicited connections and/or add security: authorization: 'enabled' in your /etc/mongod.conf. Else, anyone/anywhere can write to your DB.

And also when you want to connect to a host other than localhost or your default config, you do:

```
mongo <host>
```

means before connecting it from API you should confirm where your client is getting connected from terminal or mongo.exe and check mongod server url then make sure you are using the same in API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I forgot to mention in my question that I had already commented out the bind_ip line from my config but had no success. Thanks for the advice of using the client before trying any API!

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? If yes then I would like to know the solution.

Comment: Yes, I resolved it by starting mongod with the --bind_ip_all option.